# get all the elements that have a particular element name

Tags: c#, xml, linq-to-xml

My xml looks like this:

```
<nodes><skus><sku>abc</sku><sku>def123</sku></skus></nodes>
```

I want to get all the elements with the name 'sku'

I have a XDocument already loaded with the xml.

```
List<XElement> elements = doc.Elements.Where( ??? )
```

or would I just do:

```
doc.Elements("sku")
```

?

I don't want this to return an error if there are no elements.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    var g = XDocument.Parse("<nodes><skus><sku>abc</sku><sku>def123</sku></skus></nodes>");
    var t = from e in g.Descendants("sku")
    select e;
}
```

EDIT: I started this example, but got interrupted - I'm determined to get this code on SO even if it kills me!!

Comment: this will return a nodelist then?

Comment: *from e in g.Descendants("sku") select e* : this is the same as *g.Descendants("sku")*, it just adds one more iterator level...

Comment: @Blankman: `g.Descendants("sku")` returns `IEnumerable<XElement>`.

Answer (score 3):

`Elements()` only returns the direct children of a node.

```
doc.Descendants("sku");
```

should do the trick. It searches along the descendants axis.

Comment: shouldn't it be skus and not sku?

Comment: In your OP you wanted all sku in the document (`doc.Elements("sku")
`) so that's what I did. If you want the skus you can do `doc.Descendants("skus")` it depends what you want.

Answer (score 0):

You want a nodelist of the elements of that tag name:

```
XmlNodeList nodes = doc.GetElementsByTagName("sku");
```

Comment: The OP is using Linq to XML, not XML DOM ;)

Comment: ah. Didn't notice. Thought that xdocument was a typo of xmldocument.